# perl non-greedy replace not working at the start

Tags: regex, perl, search-regex

I am having a XML similar to this

```
<Level1Node>
.
.
    <Level2Node val="Retain"/>
.
.
</Level1Node>
<Level1Node>
.
.
    <Level2Node val="Replace"/>
.
.
</Level1Node>
<Level1Node>
.
.
    <Level2Node val="Retain"/>
.
.
</Level1Node>
```

I need to remove only the below node,

```
<Level1Node>
.
.
    <Level2Node val="Replace"/>
.
.
</Level1Node>
```

To have it replaced in non-greedy manner, I used the below regex,

```
perl -0 -pe "s|<Level1Node>.*?<Level2Node val="Retain"/>.*?</Level1Node>||gs" myxmlfile
```

But the non-geedy terminates the match only at the end of the pattern, not at the start. How to get it started at the last match of `<Level1Node>`

Comment: Please post your actual input. In your regex you have mentioned in regex as `<Level2Node>qpulse-hl7-par</Level2Node>` but in your input there is no `qpulse-hl7-par` and `level2node` having the attribute then `level2node` is self closed but you are mentioned as `</Level2Node>` in your regex.

Comment: @mkHun Updated the regex appropriately bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a negative lookahead to make sure you do not match closing `Level1Node` tags where you don't want to:

```
perl -0 -pe 's|<Level1Node>(?:(?!<\/Level1Node>).)*<Level2Node val="Retain"\/>(?:(?!<\/Level1Node>).)*<\/Level1Node>||gs' tmp.txt
```

Details:

```
<Level1Node>
(?:(?!<\/Level1Node>).)* # Everything except </Level1Node>
<Level2Node val="Retain"\/>
(?:(?!<\/Level1Node>).)* # Everything except </Level1Node>
<\/Level1Node>
```

`?:` is only here so that the parenthesis are not interpreter as a capturing group.

If you plan to run this on a large file, you should probably check the cost of the negative lookahead, it might be high.

Comment: I just found out a solution, which is almost same as yours. Thats brilliant. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper parser! It's way simpler.

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($ARGV[0]);
   $_->unbindNode() for $doc->findnodes(q{//Level1Node[Level2Node[@val!="Retain"]]});
   $doc->toFH(\*STDOUT);
' tmp.txt
```